# Magento :Update cart item Custom Option using ajax

Tags: magento

I need to update the custom option value using ajax.
I am trying to update it like

```
$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $itemID = $params['item'];
    $item =         Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemById($itemID);
    $options = $item->getOptions();

    foreach ($options as $option) {

        if(strtolower($option->getCode()) == 'info_buyRequest')
        {
            $unserialized = unserialize($option->getValue());
            $unserialized['options'][216]= 'New Value';
            $option->setValue(serialize($unserialized));

        }
    }
    $item->save();
```

Can any one help me abt what is going wrong here.
Thanks

Comment: just a wild guess.. instead of `$item->save();`, try `$item->setOptions($options)->save();`..

Comment: $item->setOptions($options)->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->save();

worked for me.
Thanks

Comment: Glad! can you please mark the answer as "accepted" so that it can help other users as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pravin got it worked with below lines of code.

```
$item->setOptions($options)->save(); 
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->save();
```

Thanks p4pravin for sharing.

Comment: It make my cart value to 0

Answer (score 2):

This can never be true:

```
(strtolower($option->getCode()) == 'info_buyRequest')
```

In addition, I had to also edit the specific saved custom option. My loop looks like this:

```
foreach ($options as $option) {
  switch (true) {
    case (strtolower($option->getCode()) == 'info_buyrequest') :
      $unserialized = unserialize($option->getValue());
      $unserialized['options'][216] = 'NEW VALUE';
      $option->setValue(serialize($unserialized));
      break;
    case ($option->getCode() == "option_216") :
      $option->setValue('NEW VALUE');
      break;
  }
}
```