# Cart items is not showing on my custom script page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I made a custom page on the magento root.my script page name is Update_cart_items.php.
I want to access the current cart items array on that page but i don't know whats wrong in that.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
 require_once 'app/Mage.php';
 umask(0);
 Mage::app('default');
 $cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart();
 print_r($cart);
?>
```

It is showing Null array. I want to get the all items array here so Please Help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below script it's working fine

```
<?php
    define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
    $mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
    require_once $mageFilename;
    Mage::init();
```

// for custom script

```
    $coreSession = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
```

/// Obtain the frontend session for custom script

```
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
    foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
       echo $productName = $item->getProduct()->getName();
       echo $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
    }


?>
```

Let Me know if you have any query

Comment: Its worked brother thanks....now i have the item array and i have custom option in that array. i want to change the custom option value for an item.

Comment: Brother now how i changed the custom option value on this custom script page

Comment: Brother please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649962/magento-update-cart-item-custom-option-using-ajax. i added this code in your foreach array but cart item's custom option is not updating ...Please help....Or do you want me to create a new question for this

Comment: @VishalSharma you can not directly update cart, you have to create to one module for that and rather then in comment you can ask new question so some one can answer your question

Comment: :Brother please help me in this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23536044/how-to-update-custom-option-value-on-cart-page

Answer (score 1):

Can you try out these :

```
    $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
    foreach ($cartItems as $item)
    {
        $productId = $item->getProductId();
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
        // Do something
    }
```

OR

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) 
{
    $productName = $item->getProduct()->getName();
    $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
}
```

One of these should work at your end.

Comment: Thanks brother for your answer but @Keyur Shah's answer worked for me ..... +1 for your help thanks again.....now i have the item array and i also have the item's custom options array. how i change the custom option value on that script

Comment: Both were the same basically :) Thanks appreciated.

Comment: @Chiragit007 answer is same but you didn't get front-end session so it didnt work , for custom script you have first get front-end session

Comment: Okay man . Your credit :) :) I thought he had idea idea related to this.

Comment: @Chiragit007: brother please help me in this question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23536044/how-to-update-custom-option-value-on-cart-page

Answer (score 0):

```
$cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
$items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems(); //echo count($items);

    foreach ($items as $item)
    {
$itemId = $item->getItemId();
}
```

Comment: i tried that when i am echo the total cart items then its showing me 0 but i have 1 product in my cart.